# How can I log information about global variables whenever these are created?

Tags: javascript, debugging, global-variables, google-chrome-devtools

### Background

I just learned that calling `keys(window)` (or `Object.keys(window)`) in the DevTools console reveals variables in the global scope ([source](https://twitter.com/ChromiumDev/status/423880231758213120)). I called that code on the StackOverflow page and got this result:

[image: StackOverflow page global variables]

Variable `i` got my attention as it seems to be in the global scope by a mistake. I tried locating code that is responsible for declaring `i`, but it turned out to be cumbersome (there is a lot of code and a lot of `i`s).

### Question

Getting console warnings that say

> Global variable "i" created (main.js:342)

could be useful. How can I implement that feature?

### Research

I figured that I need some kind of an event whenever new variable is created.

- We do have [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) in JavaScript. However, creating a setter requires that you provide a property name. Since I want to monitor all properties I can't really use that.
- `__noSuchMethod__` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod)) would be perfect but it only covers methods (and there is no `__noSuchProperty__` method).
- `Object.observe` ([HTML5 Rocks](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/11/Respond-to-change-with-Object-observe)) doesn't reveal anything about the code that created the property (`console.trace()` gives me only the name of the observer function).
- `Object.prototype.watch` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch)) - same as the setter, you have to specify a property name.
- Calling `Object.preventExtensions(window)` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions)) causes errors with a nice stack trace whenever new global variable is created. The problem with this solution is that it interferes with the script execution and may change its behaviour. It also doesn't allow me to catch the error and format it properly.

### Notes

- I know about jshint/jslint and I still think that catching these declarations in the runtime could be useful.
- I don't care about `i` variable on the SO page that much, you can probably find the declaration using setters. My question concerns the general solution for this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO you have two decent options:

1. JSHint.
2. Strict mode.

Both will yell at you when you leak a global. Strict mode will probably be better for your usecases.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I overlooked the obvious. `ReferenceError` thrown in the strict mode does have all information I need to locate the leak. I hoped for something that can be easily injected into the page (e.g. to find the mentioned leak of the `i` variable), but maybe I can force the strict mode on all scripts somehow - I'll experiment with that.

Comment: Total obvious moment.  Good call, Paul.

Comment: and closure compiler + linter.

Answer (score 1):

You've definitely done your homework, and you thought of all the things I would have thought of and, as you discovered, none of them fit.

The only way I can think of doing is to just monitor the global object (this example is using `window` as the global object: modify accordingly for Node or another JavaScript container).  Here's an example that monitors new globals and deleted globals (if you don't need to monitor deletions, you can remove that functionality):

```
var globals = Object.keys(window);
var monitorGlobalInterval = 50;

setInterval(function(){
    var globalsNow = Object.keys(window);
    var newGlobals = globalsNow.filter(function(key){
        return globals.indexOf(key)===-1;
    });
    var deletedGlobals = globals.filter(function(key){
        return globalsNow.indexOf(key)===-1;
    });
    newGlobals.forEach(function(key){
        console.log('new global: ' + key);
    });
    deletedGlobals.forEach(function(key){
        console.log('global deleted: ' + key);
    });
    globals = globalsNow;
}, monitorGlobalInterval);
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/dRjP9/2/

Comment: Thanks Ethan I appreciate your input! Your code can be simplified using `Object.observe` ([polyfill/shim](https://github.com/jdarling/Object.observe)). The issue with this solution is that we don't get any information about where variable was declared :(

Comment: Ah, right you are, Konrad.  I haven't done much work with `Object.observe`, so my mind didn't go there.  And yes, this doesn't help with declaration location, so maybe not much value to the OP.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method to get a list of global variables that you've created:

```
(function(){
  var differences = {},
    ignoreList = (prompt('Ignore filter (comma sep)?', 'jQuery, Backbone, _, $').split(/,\s?/) || []),
    iframe = document.createElement('iframe'),
    count = 0; ignoreList.push('prop');

  for (prop in window) {
    differences[prop] = {
      type: typeof window[prop],
      val: window[prop]
    }; count++;
  }

  iframe.src = 'about:blank';
  iframe.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  iframe = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument;

  for (prop in differences) {
    if (prop in iframe || ignoreList.indexOf(prop) >= 0) {
      delete differences[prop];
      count--;
    }
  }

  console.info('Total globals: %d', count);
  return differences;
})();
```